# Matlab GUIDE adding components to popup menu permanently

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I managed to add one component to my popupmenu. However once I exit the GUI, the added component is deleted once I reopen the GUI. How is it possible to save permanently?

```
function add_transducer_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to add_transducer (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

new_item= inputdlg('Please enter TEST');
new_item=char(new_item); 
tmp=get(handles.popupmenu7, 'string')
tmp{end+1}=new_item
set(handles.popupmenu7,'string',tmp) % to update the popup menu items
guidata(hObject, handles.popupmenu7);
```

As you can see, I am using a pushbutton to add a component.

Comment: I found a solution here: [http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/fig-files-format)

Comment: Please read the tag information of tags you're planning to use. I edited [guide] to [matlab-guide] now for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the gui the object is deleted and all temporary data is gone.

For persistence you'll have to store the list in a file and add each new entry to the list in the file to make the changes permanent.

i.e.

```
new_item= inputdlg('Please enter TEST');
new_item=char(new_item); 

fileContents = load('savedlist.mat'); %load previous list
list = fileContents.list; %extract from file data
list{end + 1} =  new_item; %add new item
save('savedlist.mat', 'list'); %save updated list EDIT: list MUST BE IN QUOTES
set(handles.popupmenu7,'string',tmp) % to update the popup menu items
guidata(hObject, handles.popupmenu7);
```

Comment: When I try to read with .list I am getting following comment "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array". Still relatively new so could explain me the problem? Many thanks

Comment: There's a typo there that I forgot to fix... I'll edit, but to answer your question for future use: In the previous line I load the contents of `savedlist.mat` as a struct named `fileContents.` you can view that struct by typing `fileContents` in the command window to see if it has fields in it. Chances are, it has fields named the items in your list, instead of a field named list that lists those fields.

Comment: I'm assuming that you have saved a mat file with a variable called `list` that is a cell listing the default item list.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple: save the updated GUI using [`hgsave`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsave.html).

You also have a little bug in your code sample:
Use `guidata(hObject, handles);` instead of `guidata(hObject, handles.popupmenu7);`.

Check the following code sample:

```
function add_transducer_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to add_transducer (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
new_item = inputdlg('Please enter TEST');
new_item = char(new_item);
tmp = get(handles.popupmenu7, 'string');
tmp{end+1} = new_item;
set(handles.popupmenu7, 'string', tmp) % to update the popup menu items
%guidata(hObject, handles.popupmenu7);
guidata(hObject, handles);

%Save updated GUI to 'updated_gui.fig'.
hgsave('updated_gui.fig')
```